# Properly display Chinese character from MySQL and PHP through ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How to properly display Chinese characters in HTML through ajax using PHP?

In the MySQL I have this data `èŠ±æ ·å¹´åŽ`, if I use PHP echo it shows `花样年华`, but if I use ajax callback I get `èŠ±æ ·å¹´åŽ` (eventname), the ajax code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action/getEvent.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'LoadEvent':''},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.eventname!=''){
            alert(data.eventname);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Is it I need to do something on the data before saving into MySQL database? But why PHP is ok only ajax is not?

Comment: Can you try ^contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",^ in ajax request?  (after type: "POST",)

Comment: Still the same. Should my database collation utf8_general_ci?

Comment: @4 Leave Cover I don't think so, like you said it shows chinese in php echo. I guess the problem is somewhere in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to set UTF-8 charset encoding on all of code sides, like AJAX requests[optional], PHP files with header() function, html files and also MySQL table fields charsets.